# How to pass the $http service result from directive's controller to link function

Tags: angularjs

trying to access the $http service response in controller part of the directive and store in **$scope object of controller which is not happening**,

and I want to access this scope variable in directive's link function

Below is the directive code

```
angular.module('baseapp')
.directive('renderTable',['loadService',function(loadService){
   return{
    scope:{},
    replace:true,
    controller:['$scope',function($scope){
        $scope.productsList={};
        $scope.init=function(){
            //$scope.productsList = loadService.productList;
            $scope.getAllProducts();
        }

        $scope.getAllProducts=function(){
            loadService.getData().then(function(response){  --- 

*//here I am getting the response and trying to store it in $scope which is not happening*

                $scope.productsList = response.products;
            });
        }

        $scope.init();
        console.log("$scope.productsList"+JSON.stringify($scope.productsList));
    }],
    link:function(scope,elem,attrs){
        console.log("scope.productsList"+JSON.stringify(scope.productsList));



    }
   }
}]);
```

After debugging the code what I found is before the $http code call is executing, the entire code of the directive is getting executed (asynchronous), so I am not able to store it in the variable.

For this checked some posts in the same blog found suggestions to use like promises, implemented them also, but facing the same problem, some posts showed some timers which is not working....

changed the code in all the ways I could do yet not working

Could you please suggest me some workouts for the solution

Below is the service code which is working fine I am able to inject the dependency in directive

```
angular.module('baseapp')
.service('loadService',function($http, $q){
var loadService = this;
    loadService.productList = {};

    return{
        getData : function(){
          return $http.get('./resources/js/products.json')

        }

    }

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with $rootScope and NgModelController.

Your directive could look like:

```
app.directive('renderTable', function () {

  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    replace: true,
    scope: {},
    require: 'ngModel',
    controller: function ($rootScope, $http) {

      $http.get('products.json').success(function(resp) {
        $rootScope.products = resp;
        console.log("directive's controller: " + JSON.stringify($rootScope.products));
      });

    },

    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {

      ngModelCtrl.$formatters.push(function(modelValue) {
          return modelValue;
      });

      ngModelCtrl.$render = function () {

          var products = ngModelCtrl.$viewValue;
          console.log("link function: " + JSON.stringify(products));
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Working plunk [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/jIMtnYcQ23Y0jDaAsOzf?p=info/)

See NgModelController [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController)

Comment: Thanks for the reply........ I tried your plunk its working.......but in my appliction , I am getting the below error  in the console  **TypeError: Cannot set property 'products' of undefined** ,    Below is the plunk I have created could you please check it .............  Thank you............             http://plnkr.co/edit/fohgKm7LyZknkgUBAEgZ?p=preview

Comment: your directive's controller definition is wrong. change this line "controller:[function($rootScope){" to this ->  "controller:['$rootScope', function($rootScope){" @user1245524

Comment: Thank you very much it worked......still a doubt,  the scope of the variable products is limited to ngModel.$render function only..... if we want to store it into a global variable as you did it by storing in the $rootScope.... is there any way......could you please kindly help me out, thank you so much and thanks to stackoverflow forum

Comment: my idea is to take the products.json in the link function and to build a  dynamic table with all the paging and sorting functionality

Answer (score 0):

Try $scope.productsList = response.data;

Comment: Can you post how the response object looks?

Comment: below is the json response which i get                                                                                                                        {
  "products": [
    {
      "product": "Widget",
      "description": "Amazing widgets of outstanding durability",
      "cost": 20
    },
    {
      "product": "Pants",
      "description": "Slacks for an 80s dinner party",
      "cost": 40
    },
    {
      "product": "Cow",
      "description": "Brilliant bovine",
      "cost": 60
    }
  ]
}